# JBOSS fuse Optional tag on Interface method argument

Tags: jboss, cxf, jbossfuse, javax

I have two arguments to interface method 
I have the following code

```
package com.pk.testAtrifact.incident;

public interface ServiceCountry   {
     /**
     * Operation to country
     */

    OutCountry getCountry(Header header,InputCountry input);


}
```

when it comes in WSDL it comes like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mpos:getCountry>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v1:RequestHeader>

            <!--Optional:-->
```

There is Optional tag on RequestHeader. I dont want to keep header optional. How can i do this

Comment: Try add `@XmlElement(required=true)`  like `OutCountry getCountry(@XmlElement(required=true) Header header,InputCountry input);`

Comment: its not working. Its still optional in WSDL